# whereami -r how to display specific value from result?

Tags: linux, shell, geolocation

I was wondering how can I extract an specific value from the following command?

I'm using whereami to get the computer current geolocation.

https://www.2daygeek.com/whereami-to-get-your-geolocation-information-linux-command-line/

```
whereami -r
```

The above command get's me this result

```
{
  "ip": "97.16.15.10",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "region_code": "NY",
  "region_name": "New York",
  "city": "The Bronx",
  "zip_code": "10473",
  "time_zone": "America/New_York",
  "latitude": 40.802,
  "longitude": -73.80,
  "metro_code": 501
}
```

From the result I just need the city value in this case "The Bronx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a proper json parser such as jq:

```
whereami -r | jq  '.city'
```

Sed alternative:

```
whereami -r | sed -rn 's/(^.*city": ")(.*)(".*$)/\2/p'
```

Split the response into three sections based on regular expressions. Substitute the line for the second section and print.

Comment: All I'm getting is parsing errors parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: Have you got jq installed?

Comment: Yes I installed jq.

Comment: Ok. I've added a sed alternative.